# how to prevent sql injection from this query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, yii, sql-injection

I am using Yii 1, I want to build the following query:

```
$a = Model::model()->findAllBySql(
              'SELECT * FROM table WHERE name like "%'.$_GET['name'].'%"'
              );
```

To prevent the sql injection I wrote it as follow:

```
 $a = Model::model()->findAllBySql(
                      'SELECT * FROM table WHERE name like "%:name%"',
                      array("name"=>$_GET['name'])
                      );
```

but it returned no data. Are there any errors in this query ?

Comment: "name" != :name  in your array

Comment: @DevDonkey if this query is wrong, then how to prevent sql injection.

Comment: @JayBlanchard so the key should be ":name" ?

Comment: BTW, error reporting should have given you a clue to what the problems are. Please make sure you have that enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the placeholder is quoted it is not a placeholder, it is the literal value. Try it this way:

```
$a = Model::model()->findAllBySql(
                      'SELECT * FROM table WHERE name like :name',
                      array(":name"=> '%' . $_GET['name'] . '%')
                      );
```

The driver currently auto-appends the colons but it might not in the future, it is best to have the name match the placeholder.