# 1452 > a foreign key constraint fails PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

First I know what is the mistake of the **foreign key**, however I do not know why it is happening in the PHP code with the PDO.

> Insertion Function:

```
function insert_pedido($cod,$pagamento,$total) {
    $id = $cod;
    $con = $this->connect();
    $data = date("Y/m/d");
    $DBH = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO pedido (cod_cliente, data, pagamento, total) VALUES ('?','?','?','?')");

    $DBH->bindParam(1,$id);
    $DBH->bindParam(2,$data);
    $DBH->bindParam(3,$pagamento);
    $DBH->bindParam(4,$total);

    if ($DBH->execute()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        print_r($DBH->errorInfo());
    }
}
```

> I make the function call passing these parameters

```
$cod = $_POST["cod_cliente"];
$pagamento = $_POST["pagamento"];
$total = $_POST["total"];
```

And the function call:

```
insert_pedido($cod,$pagamento,$total);
```

This is the error received:

> Array ( [0] => 23000 [1] => 1452 [2] => Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`empresa`.`pedido`, CONSTRAINT `fk_cliente` FOREIGN KEY (`cod_cliente`) REFERENCES `cliente` (`cod_cliente`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) )

As I said before, already I checked the existence of `cod_cliente` already added manually in **phpmyadmin** and it worked.

Comment: well, it can't be there, or isn't an identical match, so mysql is properly rejecting the insert. Just because something LOOKS the same in phpmyadmin doesn't mean the values actually are. try something like selecting from cliente with the exact same value that's causing this error, e.g. `select * from client where cod_client=?` and bind the exact same $_POST value.

Comment: Don't quote placeholders. The `?` are literal `?`s when quoted.

Comment: @chris85 is right maybe your problem is just the placeholders, change it to: ` (?,?,?,?)`

Comment: @chris85 I think you can add it as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to prevent sql injection from this query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178999/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-from-this-query)

Answer (score 2):

Placeholders are not strings. They should be unquoted:

```
$DBH = $con->prepare("
    INSERT INTO pedido (cod_cliente, data, pagamento, total) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
");
```

PDO will handle the process of converting your inputs into the necessary values. You can help ensure that the right type of data is submitted by specifying the type:

```
$DBH->bindParam(1, $id,   PDO::PARAM_INT);
$DBH->bindParam(2, $data, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

`PDO::PARAM_STR` is the default type.